# would like to boost the signal strength of my wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it possible to boost the signal of my wifi, i keep getting disconnected from xbox live.  I do not wish to boost the range (loads of products state range) of the signal but the actual connection strength of the signal. is this possible?

Comment: Is moving the xbox closer to the wifi access point is an option? If not, then getting a new wifi access point that has stronger signal is an option. Do you get good signal where it is now?

Comment: I get a good signal, full bars and i am about 5ft away and i have checked the signal when i have been disconnected from xbox live and it showed that i had gone down from four bars to three. with such a small margin for error i just wonder if it's possible to boost connection strength. i have 4 g coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **it depends** on your router and firmware combination.

On my ancient Linksys WRT54G, I installed a 3rd party firmware (Hyperwrt) which enabled me to boost the transmitting power of the router's radio signal.

You'll have to research this, but some of today's DD-WRT and similar 3rd party firmwares may also have this hack.

Comment: thank you. just google it and it is supported. i will post results

Comment: Careful with boosting the signal on one end.  The Access Point will be able to shout at a greater distance and will be heard by your xbox, but your xbox will not be able to shout back to the Access Point at the same signal strength level.  Repositioning your xbox or access point is your best option.